# maven multimodule project: can I jar-with-dependencies?

Tags: java, maven, jar, maven-assembly-plugin, multi-module

I have a maven project, with a main project A and modules B and C.  The children inherit from A's pom.

```
A
|
|----B
|    |----pom.xml
|
|----C
|    |----pom.xml
| 
|----pom.xml
```

It already builds jars for all the modules.  Is there a way to include the dependencies in those jars?  E.g. so I get `B-1.0-with-dependencies.jar` and `C-1.0-with-dependencies.jar`?  I have tried setting

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

In the parent pom, but it doesn't seem to do anything: the build succeeds, but I get regular, no-dependency jars.

I'd like to avoid putting something in each child pom, as in reality I have more than 2 modules.  I'm sure there is some way to do this, but can't seem to work it out from the maven docs.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is how I made it work.
In the aggregator/parent pom I configured:

```
<properties>
    <skip.assembly>true</skip.assembly>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <skipAssembly>${skip.assembly}</skipAssembly>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Note the `skip.assembly` property, which is set by default to `true`. That means the assembly would not be executed on the parent, which makes sense since the parent doesn't provide any code (having packaging `pom`).

Then, in each module I configured simply the following:

```
<properties>
    <skip.assembly>false</skip.assembly>
</properties>
```

Which means in each submodule the skip is disabled and the assembly is executed as configured in the parent. Moreover, with such a configuration, you can also easily skip the assembly for a certain module (if required).

Please also note the assembly configuration on the parent, I added an `execution` on top of the configuration you provided so that the assembly plugin is triggered automatically when invoking `mvn clean package` (or `mvn clean install`).

Comment: Fantastic!  One note for anyone else running into this: I wanted to copy the jars into the main-level `target/` dir, using `<classifier>jar-with-dependencies</classifier>`.  To do so, I had to put the maven-assembly-plugin ahead of maven-dependency plugin in the parent pom, otherwise the jar-with-dependencies wasn't built before maven tried to copy it over.  Didn't know plugin order mattered!

Comment: This didn't work for me. I'm using assembly plugin v3.1. Any idea why this maybe the case?

Comment: It worked when I used: `mvn clean compile assembly:single` instead of `mvn package`. Maybe the assembly step was not hooked up with the package step, I'm not sure.

Comment: @AhmedMoawad building my project with `mvn clean compile assembly:single` gives me `Error reading assemblies: No assembly descriptors found.`. Building with `mvn clean package` gives me JARs with dependencies but without my sources... It's a Kotlin project, but when there was no parent it worked fine.